# Divide Numpy array by Scalar where Array-Element is below a certain value

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array like

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

Now I want divide every Element which is less than 5 by 2. The Result should be

```
[[0.5, 1, 1.5],
 [2, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use `numpy.where`:

```
np.where(arr<5, arr/2, arr)
```

Output:

```
array([[0.5, 1. , 1.5],
       [2. , 5. , 6. ],
       [7. , 8. , 9. ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by logical indexing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]], dtype = float)
>>> x[x<5] = x[x<5]/2
>>> x
array([[0.5, 1. , 1.5],
       [2. , 5. , 6. ],
       [7. , 8. , 9. ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you could do

```
x[x<5] = x[x<5]/2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numpy.where
```

For example, if your array is named `np_array`

```
numpy.where(np_array >=5, np_array, np_array/2)
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)